# Selecting files with one extensions that have the same name as files with a different extension

Tags: terminal, finder, file

I have two folders of images. In one folder there are `.JPGs`, e.g.

> - 001.jpg
> - 002.jpg
> - 003.jpg
> - 004.jpg
> - 005.jpg
> - 006.jpg
> - 007.jpg
> - 008.jpg

in the other folder, there are `.NEF`s. However some of the `.NEF`s have been deleted, so there are e.g.

> - 001.nef
> - 003.nef
> - 004.nef
> - 005.nef
> - 008.nef

The jpgs and nefs correspond to one another - they are the same photograph taken at the same time with the same efix data (saved to two seperate memory cards)

What I want to do is select the .JPGs that correspond to the remaining .NEFs. In the above example I want to select **JPGs 1,3,4,5,8** but not the others. I actually have around 400 jpgs and 800 nefs.

I have tried using folder comparison apps such as VisualDiffer however they seem to only work if you're using the same full file name + extension.

Does anybody know how it might be possible to achieve this in finder or using terminal? or alternatively with a different app?

I am using Mac OSX 10.6.8

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with the files once they are selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open terminal and use cd to make the directory of *.nef files your current directory. Let's assume you have this structure:

mydir/jpegdir
mydir/nefdir

So cd into mydir/nefdir

Then:

```
mkdir newdir
for file in *.nef; do 
    root=${$file%.nef}; 
    jpeg=${root}.jpg; 
    mv ../jpegdir/${jpeg} ./newdir/
done
```

example below. Note here that I put "echo" in front of the mv command. You want to omit that, but I often use it when I'm checking that a script is doing what I expect before executing it. You also don't say what you want to do with the files, but moving them to a new folder allows you to select them, and you can always move them all back. I also shortened my tmp variable names.

```
$ ls -R
total 0
drwxrwxr-x  4 tim  staff  136 Jun 13 08:02 .
drwx------  9 tim  staff  306 Jun 13 08:02 ..
drwxrwxr-x  8 tim  staff  272 Jun 13 08:03 jpegdir
drwxrwxr-x  5 tim  staff  170 Jun 13 08:03 nefdir

./jpegdir:
total 0
drwxrwxr-x  8 tim  staff  272 Jun 13 08:03 .
drwxrwxr-x  4 tim  staff  136 Jun 13 08:02 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 tim  staff    0 Jun 13 08:03 foo1.jpeg
-rw-rw-r--  1 tim  staff    0 Jun 13 08:03 foo2.jpeg
-rw-rw-r--  1 tim  staff    0 Jun 13 08:03 foo3.jpeg
-rw-rw-r--  1 tim  staff    0 Jun 13 08:03 foo4.jpeg
-rw-rw-r--  1 tim  staff    0 Jun 13 08:03 foo5.jpeg
-rw-rw-r--  1 tim  staff    0 Jun 13 08:03 foo6.jpeg

./nefdir:
total 0
drwxrwxr-x  5 tim  staff  170 Jun 13 08:03 .
drwxrwxr-x  4 tim  staff  136 Jun 13 08:02 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 tim  staff    0 Jun 13 08:03 foo2.nef
-rw-rw-r--  1 tim  staff    0 Jun 13 08:03 foo3.nef
-rw-rw-r--  1 tim  staff    0 Jun 13 08:03 foo5.nef

$ cd nefdir/
$ mkdir newdir/

$ for f in *.nef; do g=${f%.nef}; h=$g.jpeg; echo mv ../jpegdir/$h ./newdir; done
mv ../jpegdir/foo2.jpeg ./newdir
mv ../jpegdir/foo3.jpeg ./newdir
mv ../jpegdir/foo5.jpeg ./newdir
```